Migrating from Money Manager Ex - QIF Import
I'm migrating to GnuCash from Money Manager Ex (MMEX) with 8 years of transactions. I've tried exporting accounts and transactions with QIF files but I always get the same error:
"Missing QIF investment action for transaction dated XX-XX-XX".
I've tried to see if I can spot the error in the QIF file but I can't see anything out of the ordinary. I've even deleted all transactions of said data and it only moves the error to another date.
Any experience or suggestions on how to migrate from MMEX to GnuCash?

Is the error just in one account? If so, transfer all the rest, then try a divide - and - conquer approach on this one. Export/import the earliest half of the transactions and see if that works. If it does then transfer half of what remains, and so on until you find the transactions which are complaining. Then you can export everything after those transactions, and just copy those by hand. Or, if you prefer, just copy everything since that time and not worry about the older history, adjusting the account's starting balance appropriately.
QIF is less documented and more fragile than it should be, since everyone had to reverse engineer it from Quicken's behavior, and things which don't exactly match between programs may not be represented in a compatible form.

It seems this is a generic error, it wrongly identifies a transaction as an investment transaction while it's not. For example, for the transaction below it throws the same error but I don't see anything wrong with it.
!Type:Bank
D25-09-17
CR
T584.64
PCompany
LIncome:Salary

Talk to the folks who wrote the importing software you're trying to use and ask them what their program doesn't like about that entry. They're the ones who would know why it fails.
